# How does the html id attribute work

Tags: html

Can anyone please explain in details how the id attribute actually works in html? Is is used to create a link of my own document or something like that?

Comment: Google is your best bet to find all your answers: A good resource is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id).

Comment: BTW: Why is this downvoted? Everybody started once without any understanding of the matter. So as this is a programming resource, give eachother a chance.

Comment: Thank you markus. And if I get downvoted for asking questions that i feel the need to ask, then how will I do that?

Comment: I recommend you to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also try something yourself before asking a question about it then provide the code you have in that question so others can find out where you're struggling. Thats the best you can do to avoid being downvoted. And keep friendly and clear language of course :P Oh, and have a google before you ask. The answer might already be out there (like asked and answered a million times, which will get you downvoted as well).

Answer (score 0):

It is used by numerous javascript libraries for selecting an element with the specified id, and vanilla-js by `document.getElementById`

It is used to apply styles in css:

```
#id{

}
```

It is used for hash navigation as well.

IDs have to be unique.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id)

> `IDs` purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment
>   identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

BTW you have a whole new theory of ids!

Comment: doc is public. I only copied the your link in the comment.. :)

Comment: Yea of course it's public and I encourage everybody to use and share it! So no problem :-P

Comment: I still don't understand it :( I have started learning html. Is it like creating a link to a specific section of my document? For example, if i create a paragraph describing effects of pollution and give it an id="description", and create a link <a href="#id">Pollution</a> then it will direct me to that paragraph?

Comment: but when i write down a code, then the whole code is displayed. For example i want to create an id that will direct me to that pollution paragraph. But if i write the code and when i try to open it, the paragraph is there. But i dont want the paragraph to display before i click the link.

Comment: @raiyan106 I recommend you to follow a html tutorial to start understanding the basics of setting up and structuring a website document. Then continue with using the ID attribute. [This one](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/tags/) is a good starting point. Also check out CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) and using IDs to style elements. Learning this will also help you understand how IDs work and for what they are used.

Comment: Thanks markus, i am learning html from w3schools.com coz I heard it is the best for learning web developing languages

Comment: @raiyan106 Check these out for info on w3schools: [Link 1](http://www.w3fools.com/), [Link 2](http://www.impressivewebs.com/w3schools-ugly-bad-good/), [Link 3](http://webdesign.about.com/b/2011/04/06/i-had-no-idea.htm). **I just don't advise to use w3schools as the only learning resource.**

Answer (score 0):

> The `ID` attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

(Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id)